# Virtual function

Tags: c++, opencv

In the computer vision library, the base class DescriptorExtractor (used to extract descriptors from keypoints in one image) is written like that :

```
class DescriptorExtractor
{
public:
  virtual ~DescriptorExtractor();
  void compute( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
protected:
  virtual void computeImpl(const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const = 0;
};
```

And for different types of descriptors, like Surf of Sift, we derive from base class:

```
class SurfDescriptorExtractor : public DescriptorExtractor
{
public:
  SurfDescriptorExtractor(..){..}
protected:
  virtual void computeImpl(const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
  SURF surf;
};
```

And the protected method computeImpl is (re)implemented.
I wrote a new descriptor extractor `MyDescriptorExtractor` which need current image (as others in opencv) and previous image too like that (?):

```
class MyDescriptorExtractor: public DescriptorExtractor
{
public:
  ...
protected:
  virtual void computeImpl(const Mat& image, const Mat& prev_image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
}
```

I want this new class to be compatible with opencv  methods using `DescriptorExtractor` as argument. What is the best way to do this ? Problem is that base class method `compute` will not have the same signature ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that subclassing should still obey the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Still, the solution is to pass the parameter you need in the constructor of `MyDescriptorExtractor`, which allows you to keep the same signature.

Comment: I imagine a method of `MyDescriptorExtractor` called `keepHistory` that has to be run. Anyway I find these options a little dirty ...